# remove \r\n from output

Tags: php, mysql

I know this question has been asked before but the answers are not the solution to my problem.

When i post a text with this code:

```
$info=html_entity_decode(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['info']));
```

Like :

```
fdsa

fdsa

fasf
```

and when i posted this text with antered and spaces it looks like this

```
<?php echo $info;?>

fdsa\r\nfdsa\r\nfasf\r\n
```

i try this  `nl2br($info)`  but still not working.

What do I need to appear in the text in this way?

```
fdsa

fdsa

fasf
```

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: @georg Because this part of the user input part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the `\r\n` by `<br>`, the `\n` by `<br>`, then the`\r` by `<br>`:

```
$info = html_entity_decode($_POST['info']); 
$info = str_replace('\r\n' , '<br>', $info);
$info = str_replace('\n' , '<br>', $info);
$info = str_replace('\r' , '<br>', $info);

$info = html_entities($info);
echo $info;
```

You have to make multiples replacements since new lines can be represented differently according to the operating system (See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) for more details)

Finally, sanitize the value with [`html_entities`](http://php.net/manual/enfunction.htmlentities.php) before echoing it, preventing client side attacks.

EDIT : Removed the mysql_... function, not needed (the value isn't intended to be inserted in a MySQL database, not now at least).

Also, read Lashus advice bellow and apply it ;)

Comment: Again as in many post - stop using **mysql** functions. They are deprecated since php 5.5 and won't be supported in future versions. Use at least **mysqli** or **pdo** extension instead.

Comment: I've just completed his/her code with what he/she needed, it appears he/she doesn't even need this function.

Comment: Still, always try to point that to newbies. They will avoid a lot of problems in the future

Comment: @Veve Thank you for this beautiful and clear explanations. It was a real solution for me.

Comment: Plus 1 for concise explanation and references.

Comment: Because it's a control character, and it's the way new lines are represented. Look at the linked Wikipedia page for more info ;)

Comment: @Veve this code will work. Can you tell me what do you think about this code for remove control character ? `<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>`